# Karma cannot connect to Chrome in Windows 7

Tags: google-chrome, karma-runner

- `karma start` Launches Chrome with correct URL but Chrome just sits there and spins.  Also, no other url will work in that window that Karma launched.
- Same behavior with Canary
- Similar issue with FireFox
- Opera and IE work!
- if I copy/paste the URL into a functioning Chrome browser, it CONNECTS but after the original test window times out the server shuts down
- For some reason I cannot launch Chrome with the user-data flag: `--user-data-dir=C:\tmp\karma-7572069` -- it's the same behavior... the browser just spins and no other url works in that window
- deleted all user profiles in Chrome & Firefox and re-installed them both... no go

ANY SUGGESTIONS?

After googling and pouring over umpteen similar SO issues I thought for sure it had to do with a corrupt user profile... but after wiping the Chrome user folder and re-installing etc, what else could I try?

- Karma: `0.12.28`
- Chrome: `39.0.2171.95 m`
- Windows 7

debug log:

```
DEBUG [config]: Loading config d:\Code\test2\karma.conf.js
DEBUG [plugin]: Loading karma-* from d:\Code\test2\node_modules
DEBUG [plugin]: Loading plugin d:\Code\test2\node_modules/karma-chrome-launcher.
DEBUG [plugin]: Loading plugin d:\Code\test2\node_modules/karma-firefox-launcher.
DEBUG [plugin]: Loading plugin d:\Code\test2\node_modules/karma-ie-launcher.
DEBUG [plugin]: Loading plugin d:\Code\test2\node_modules/karma-jasmine.
DEBUG [plugin]: Loading plugin d:\Code\test2\node_modules/karma-opera-launcher.
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.12.28 server started at http://localhost:9876/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
DEBUG [temp-dir]: Creating temp dir at C:\tmp\karma-7572069
DEBUG [launcher]: C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --user-data-dir=C:\tmp\karma-7572069 --no-default-browser-check --no-first-run --disable-default-apps --disable-popup-blocking --disable-translate http://localhost:9876/?id=7572069
DEBUG [watcher]: Resolved files:
        d:/Code/test2/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js
        d:/Code/test2/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/boot.js
        d:/Code/test2/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/adapter.js
WARN [launcher]: Chrome have not captured in 60000 ms, killing.
DEBUG [launcher]: Process Chrome exited with code 0
DEBUG [temp-dir]: Cleaning temp dir C:\tmp\karma-7572069
INFO [launcher]: Trying to start Chrome again (1/2).
DEBUG [launcher]: Restarting Chrome
DEBUG [temp-dir]: Creating temp dir at C:\tmp\karma-7572069
DEBUG [launcher]: C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --user-data-dir=C:\tmp\karma-7572069 --no-default-browser-check --no-first-run --disable-default-apps --disable-popup-blocking --disable-translate http://localhost:9876/?id=7572069
WARN [launcher]: Chrome have not captured in 60000 ms, killing.
DEBUG [launcher]: Process Chrome exited with code 0
DEBUG [temp-dir]: Cleaning temp dir C:\tmp\karma-7572069
INFO [launcher]: Trying to start Chrome again (2/2).
DEBUG [launcher]: Restarting Chrome
DEBUG [temp-dir]: Creating temp dir at C:\tmp\karma-7572069
DEBUG [launcher]: C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --user-data-dir=C:\tmp\karma-7572069 --no-default-browser-check --no-first-run --disable-default-apps --disable-popup-blocking --disable-translate http://localhost:9876/?id=7572069
WARN [launcher]: Chrome have not captured in 60000 ms, killing.
DEBUG [launcher]: Process Chrome exited with code 0
DEBUG [temp-dir]: Cleaning temp dir C:\tmp\karma-7572069
ERROR [launcher]: Chrome failed 2 times (timeout). Giving up.
DEBUG [launcher]: Disconnecting all browsers
```

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out.  My console was being run as a non-admin.  Booo.  Now everything works.

Comment: Thanks for this hint. My Bash console was set up to always run in "Run as admin" mode and I could not figure out what was the problem of Chrome crashing while using Karma. After running it in normal mode everything worked great!